# How do I publish a nupkg to "Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages"?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, visual-studio-2019

I have built a nupkg of NSec (master), since I need unreleased features. Now, I wish to publish this nupkg in my local Nupkg repository, so that I can include it from other projects.

I tried:

```
nuget.exe push *.nupkg -source "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\"
```

But I get the following error message:

```
Pushing NSec.Cryptography.19.10.0-preview1-28213-71.nupkg to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages"'...
Illegal characters in path.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try escaping the white spaces with ‘\’?

Btw, You can add your packages any local folder and add that folder as your NuGet feed. See how to add sources (feed) here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources

Comment: Solved by just using a random directory as you mention.